# How to create a COM Dll in C++ that exposes a function which returns an object?

Tags: c++, dll, com, idl

I am having a WCF (C# application) application that makes a call to a C++COM Dll. Now the method exposed by C++ COM dll has the following signature.

```
STDMETHODIMP MessageControl::CallMe(eEventType eventTypeVal, OUT long *pVal)
```

Now instead of returning a long *pVal I would like to return a interface which has multiple properties. Something like -

```
STDMETHODIMP MessageControl::CallMe(eEventType eventTypeVal, OUT IData *pVal)
```

So for the new interface how should I update the COM DLL? So Should I add a new entry in the IDL file for IData interface. I am new to this COM C++ Dll.

Comment: if IData represents an interface, yes, you should declare it in idl, like any other interface (so the idl compiler can compile it). You can define it in the same .idl or in another .idl and include it.

Comment: @SimonMourier ok , but can you show me a sample like what would be the way to write an interface like IData in the idl file, which will have two properties let say DriverName and DriverId and would be string type?

Comment: Do you have an existing idl? properties are a notion for dispinterface not interface (where everything is a method): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/anatomy-of-an-idl-file

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a function in your IDL like (assuming your interface is IMessageControl):

```
interface IMessageControl
{
   STDMETHOD(CallMe)(eEventType eventTypeVal, [out,retval] IData** pVal);
}
```

or if you want option to return long or an object

```
interface IMessageControl
{
   STDMETHOD(CallMe)(eEventType eventTypeVal, [out,retval] VARIANT* pVal);
}
```

Your C++ code would be something like:

```
STDMETHODIMP MessageControl::CallMe(eEventType eventTypeVal, IData** pVal)
{
   return E_NOTIMPL;
}
```

or for variant version

```
STDMETHODIMP MessageControl::CallMe(eEventType eventTypeVal, VARIANT* pVal)
{
   return E_NOTIMPL;
}
```

Obviously, once you implement, return S_OK for good return or an E_ type error code for a failure.